# Read current CPU frequency

Tags: android, cpu, bufferedreader, frequency, processbuilder

I try to read the current cpu frequency. After some research i've found the following code:

```
public String ReadCPUMhz2() throws IOException
{
      String[] args = {"/system/bin/cat", "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq"};

      ProcessBuilder cmd;
      cmd = new ProcessBuilder(args);
      Process process = null;
      process = cmd.start();

      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

      StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();

      String line;
      Log.d("test","aha");
      while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        log.append(line + "\n");
      }
      Log.d("test",log.toString());
      return log.toString();
}
```

But that doesnt do anything. Logcat shows the "aha" before the while-loop, but "log" seems to be empty. I can't see what i did wrong :s ?

PS: Sorry for the bad English.

Answer (score 9):

cpuinfo_max_freq will give you the maximum frequency not the current one. There is another value, scaling_cur_freq (found at /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq) that will give you the current frequency.

The way I access cpuinfo_max_freq is this, maybe you could apply this to scaling_cur_freq and see if it works?

```
String cpuMaxFreq = "";
    RandomAccessFile reader = new RandomAccessFile("/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq", "r");
    cpuMaxFreq = reader.readLine();
    reader.close();
```

Comment: This works to get the max frequency, but trying to grab the current frequency returns the max frequency as well.